# Scaffold common base class for all entities without discriminator

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, npgsql, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Scaffold creates Poco classes like

```
namespace MyDbContext
{
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
   }
}
```

How to force it to generate common base class for all entities like

```
    public partial class Customer : EntityBase
    { }
```

Inheritance generates discriminator field. EntityBase class not have database properties freom database. So discriminator field generation is useless.
How to disable discriminator field generation ?

Scaffold is perfomed at runtime. So it it not possible to manually change created code or add partial classes for every table.
Docs in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding does not describe such option in

```
dotnet ef dbcontext
```

command.

This is ASP.NET 5 MVC application using Npgsql EF Core data provider.

Comment: No such out-of-the-box functionality so far. Check [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/), there a couple which try to address the issue.

Comment: Inheritance generates discriminator field. EntityBase class not have database properties freom database. So discriminator field generation is useless.
How to disable discriminator field generation ?

Comment: Do not register `EntityBase` as entity - i.e. no `DbSet<EntityBase`, no `EntityBase`  or `ICollection<EntityBase>` and similar navigation properties, no fluent `modelBuilder.Entity<EntityBase>` calls etc. - nothing which can cause `EntityBase` to be [included in the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#including-types-in-the-model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple thinking. no reversed engineering can detect common part of your entities. More, assumption you have many entities: E1, E2, E3, E4. When you scaffold E1, E2, E3 at one time, then you scaffold E4 at second time, how to detect mutual part of first time and second time.

Therefore, logical thinking shows you that has no tool as you expected.

You can done your task manually:

- Generate entity POCO automatically
- Create a base class
- Delete properties what are mutually
- Extend from base class

Comment: EntityBase class contains business logic. It does not contain any properties from database. Inheritance causes discriminator field generation which is useless. How to disable discriminator field generation ?

Comment: I see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext , your need has no existing out-of-the-box feature.